# Trick for Inverse Hollow Matrix Calculation (Self-Answered)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $A$ be the *hollow matrix* :
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&1&1\\
1&0&1&1\\
1&1&0&1\\
1&1&1&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Find the inverse matrix $A^{-1}$ **without using any elementary row/ column operations.**

Comment: What do you mean by "a hollow matrix" ?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that 
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1
\end{pmatrix} - I_{4\times4}
$$

Let 
$$
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

then $B=A+I$. Observe that $B^2 = (A+I)^2=4B$. Expanding, 
$$
A^2+2A+I = 4(A+I) \implies A^2-2A=3I
$$
Therefore $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{3}(A-2I)$.

More generally, this method gives us an easy way to express the inverse of a hollow matrix $A$ (of the particular stated form) of any order $n$, which is the main reason for posting this question.

Comment: You can generalize this to $\alpha I+\beta B$.

Comment: This is in fact a classical method, with the use of Cayley-Hamilton theorem (see https://yutsumura.com/find-the-inverse-matrix-using-the-cayley-hamilton-theorem/) in general, or the minimal polynomial.